# Update query is updating entire row instead of one in mysql using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure in mysql for updating the data but when I call the function it updates entire row instead of one

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdVend`(
    in vid nvarchar (50),
    in vName nvarchar(100),
    in addres nvarchar(250),
    in phone int(11),
    in email nvarchar(50),
    in pan nvarchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
    UPDATE visitor SET VName = vName, Addres = addres, Phone = phone, Email = email,Pan = pan WHERE VId = vid;
END
```

When I call this it updates entire row.
before this it was showing error 1175 about update safe mode. I solved it out by using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0`;

Comment: Your table schema ? Can you show it ?

Comment: What do you mean entire row instead of one? Do you mean updating all rows?

Comment: i am trying to update the records that match according to where clause but it is actually updating all the rows entire table. simple query is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple change and its working...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdVend`(
in vid nvarchar (50),
in vName nvarchar(100),
in addres nvarchar(250),
in phone int(11),
in email nvarchar(50),
in pan nvarchar(100)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE visitor v SET VName = vName, Addres = addres, Phone = phone, Email = email,Pan = pan WHERE v.VId = vid;
END
```